# Is there a easy to follow tutorial on how to get multi sig working for Monero v12 via console?

Tags: multisig

Monero v12 is out and there's multi sig, but I'm unsure how to go about using this on the command line. Is there an easy visual tutorial on how to go about using this?

Comment: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/5646/how-to-use-monero-multisignature-wallets-2-2-2-3