# Offline Signing 2/3 Multisig

Tags: security, multisig, messagesigning

Interested in weather offline signing for 2/3 Multisig wallets is possible in this setup.

I have three computers Airgapped from the internet, and a USB. I imagine i can pull down some outputs for the ring signature creation from the blockchain from a online connected computer. I put these outputs onto a USB stick and transfer them to computer A, A conducts some offline signing process and builds the transaction, then i transfer on a USB A's signed TX + key image which B also signs. then that tx is taken to the online computer and submitted to the network.

So i have some questions, is the process described above possible? if so how would i get the data from the online computer into computer A, IE how does the process work is there some command in the CLI?

Answer (score 1):

Details of multisig in the answers to this question: [How to Use Monero Multisignature Wallets (2/2 & 2/3)](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/5646/how-to-use-monero-multisignature-wallets-2-2-2-3)

But no, actual signing doesn't need to be done while online.