# Cold multisig wallet

Tags: multisig

I'm trying to sign a multisig transaction offline following [multisig](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/5646/how-to-use-monero-multisignature-wallets-2-2-2-3) and [offline](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/is-there-any-way-to-construct-a-transaction-manually/2916) guides.

I got stuck when I tried to transfer funds, because the online view only wallet can't create multisig transaction and the offline signer wallet needs a daemon.

Is this even possible right now?

Answer (score 1):

There is no code for doing cold multisig. There is not really much point since you can have one of your multisig wallets on an offline machine already, so adding a cold/hot system would not really add much I think.

If a multisig wallet on an offline machine cannot sign without a dameon, that should be fixed as I don't think it's inherently needed.