# How to construct a transaction with multiple inputs (joint payments)?

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-rpc

I sometimes encounter Monero transactions with more than two inputs. If I have access to multiple wallets, how do I construct a transaction with multiple inputs from different wallets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I sometimes encounter Monero transactions with more than two inputs.

This is very common and happens automatically. Your wallet uses outputs it receives, as inputs to fund a transaction. Sometimes your wallet will need to use multiple outputs (as inputs), to fund a transaction. This however is different from your question:

> If I have access to multiple wallets, how do I construct a transaction with multiple inputs from different wallets?

To send/join funds from *different wallets* you need to first send funds from each of the wallets in question to a single wallet that will do the ultimate spending. This could also be a multisig wallet if there are more wallet owners than just yourself.

A couple of guides:

- https://monerodocs.org/multisignature/
- https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/5647/7493

Comment: Multisig sends from the same wallet, not from different wallets.

Comment: Multisig requires multiple wallets (participants private keys) ,to sign a transaction to be able to spend/send it.

Comment: I'm not going through your tortured logic hoops again, so this'll be my last comment here: multisig is ONE wallet, created from the data from several precusor wallets. You don't send outputs from those precusor wallets, but from the single multisig one.

Comment: Not sure of the need for the "tortured logic" comment. A multisig tx is signed by multiple private keys, each owned by the participants of the multisig scheme. They each have a wallet which has their own private key. Sure, one can define the multisig wallet as one wallet shared amongst the participants, but the wallet does not contain all the participants private keys. You'd be sending outputs from the precusor wallets to the multisig wallet and each participant could then sign a tx in each of their version of the multisig wallet (signing with their private key).

Answer (score 1):

It is theoretically possible send a transaction using outputs from different wallets, but there is no tooling for this currently. The idea is that each participating wallet will sign only the rings for the outputs they are spending. There is a proof of concept for this in https://github.com/moneromooo-monero/bitmonero/tree/multi but it turns out the mapping from inputs to outputs can't be made private, so it did not go any further, though I believe it works if you don't mind that drawback.

So AFAIK all transactions currently on the blockchain with more than one input spend from the same wallet.