# code=-28, message=This wallet is already multisig

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

i follow the tutorial to create multisig;

```
https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/5646/how-to-use-monero-multisignature-wallets-2-2-2-3
```

when i create another multisig address , the wallet rpc return error.

```
id=0, error={code=-28, message=This wallet is already multisig}
```

i want create many different multisig address to provider merchant use.

what should i do, what the best practice?

Comment: one merchant three wallet (2/3) ? i don't think it's a best way

Answer (score 1):

You're apparently trying to switch a multisig wallet to multisig. Which it already is. That's what it's telling you. Start with a non multisig wallet to make it multisig. You have nothing to do turn a multisig wallet multisig, since it already is.