# How can I combine two public keys to create a joint address?

Tags: address

I'm trying to create a new address that either Alice OR Bob can spend from.

Is there a tool or library I can use to accomplish this?

At a high level:

- I'm taking (AlicePrivateSpend + BobPrivateSpend) to make JointPrivateSpend
- Multiply by G to get JointPublicSpend.
- Repeat this to get public/private View keys.
- Create the Monero-variant
  Base58 encoded address.

To test, I go to the wallet and try to recover from keys. The joint address cannot be verified.

I verified that my address encoding is working OK in two different libraries. The problem is in my key generation, which I can elaborate on with code snippets if necessary, but the root of the question is, does this library or code already exist?

Comment: https://web.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/multisig-messaging-system.html & https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/5646/how-to-use-monero-multisignature-wallets-2-2-2-3 ?

Comment: can it be done without multisig? i think i phrased my question wrong? i need to make the address jointly from the private keys. Alice and Bob will both know the private keys.

Comment: 1-of-N multisig is unfortunately not supported...

Comment: I don't think your use case makes any sense. Can you name a single advantage of your scheme vs Alice and Bob simply both knowing the private key of a wallet they both share?