# Multisig wallets cannot spend non rct outputs

Tags: multisig

I'm experimenting with multisig wallet on private testnet. I have followed this tutorial: [How to Use Monero Multisignature Wallets (2/2 & 2/3)](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/5646/how-to-use-monero-multisignature-wallets-2-2-2-3) but when I try to transfer from multisig wallet I get:

```
{
  error: {
    code: -4,
    message: 'Multisig wallets cannot spend non rct outputs'
  },
  id: 0,
  jsonrpc: '2.0'
}
```

What's the reason and how can I overcome it?

Answer (score 1):

This was not implemented. Multisig came after rct, so there should not be pre-rct outputs in multisig wallets. It is possible to have code that spends those, it's just that there is no such code currently.

Comment: So what can I do to test multisig on private testnet? Do I have to generate certain amount of blocks?

Comment: Just sync it till at least v4 (IIRC) first.