# What signature scheme does Monero use for multisig?

Tags: multisig

How do multisig transactions work in Monero? Does it use a threshold signature scheme? Or is it like bitcoin where there is an M-of-N Multisig Operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial support detailed here:
[How to Use Monero Multisignature Wallets (2/2 & 2/3)](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/5646/how-to-use-monero-multisignature-wallets-2-2-2-3)

Then arbitrary M/N was [added later](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/commit/9f3963e8235826704b7bc6ef9e3b90613a72e16c#diff-2d253f78e9fe6685bc17f79b4aafa0e823b3b62243daea78d0bba36eeeeaf822).